# Simpler way to do this proof for congruences of integers?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to do practice problems on proofs involving congruences of integers but I am stuck on half of the problem in that I am not able to consider a more simplified solution as opposed to brute forcing it. The problem is as follows:

Let $x$ and $y$ be even integers. Prove that $16 \mid (x^2 - y^2)$ iff either (1) $4 \mid x$ and $4 \mid y$ or (2) $4 \mid (x-2)$ and $4 \mid (y-2)$

Let P be the statement that: $16 \mid (x^2 - y^2)$

Let Q be the statement that: either (1) $4 \mid x$ and $4 \mid y$ or (2) $4 \mid (x-2)$ and $4 \mid (y-2)$

Basically, the implication $Q \implies P$ should be quite easy to prove but I am a bit stuck on proving $P \implies Q \equiv \thicksim Q \implies \thicksim P$

I thought about doing a contrapositive for the implication of $P \implies Q$ but then I noticed that there would be over 8 cases to consider since $\thicksim Q: (4\not\mid x \text{ or } 4\not\mid y) \text{ and } (4\not\mid (x-2) \text{ or } 4\not\mid (y-2))$. Hence this would result in too many cases to consider so is there a more simpler solution to this or would I consider all the possible cases of $\thicksim Q$? I'm not really sure how I could go about directly proving that $P \implies Q$ as opposed to using the contrapositive.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the tool you are missing is modular arithmetic.
$$16|(x^2-y^2) \Leftrightarrow x^2\equiv y^2 \pmod {16} \Leftrightarrow x^2-y^2\equiv 0 \pmod {16} \Leftrightarrow (x-y)(x+y) \equiv 0 \pmod {16}$$
Then you can just consider what the conditions are to have $ab\equiv 0 \pmod{16}$

Comment: Ah I se in that case I could directly proof the implication that $p /implies q$ as opposed to considering the contra positive right ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls presumably, yes.